# Different behaviour for Flux.doOnEach and Flux.doOnNext with Flux.publishOn

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to understand consequences of publishOn with doOnEach operator and empty Flux. I have a simple test:

```java
private static void incrementOnNext(AtomicInteger value, Signal<String> signal) {
  if (signal.isOnNext()) {
    value.incrementAndGet();
  }
}

@Test
void incrementTest() {
  AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(0);
  StepVerifier.create(
          Flux.just("Test text")
              .doOnEach(signal -> incrementOnNext(value, signal))
              .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
              .doOnEach(signal -> incrementOnNext(value, signal))
              .doOnEach(signal -> incrementOnNext(value, signal))
              .filter(String::isEmpty))
      .verifyComplete();
  assertThat(value.get()).isEqualTo(3);
}
```

I expect this test to pass. However, doOnEach is executed just once and I do not understand why. What's more - if I change doOnEach with doOnNext test works as expected:

```java
@Test
void incrementTestOnNext() {
  AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(0);
  StepVerifier.create(
          Flux.just("Test text")
              .doOnNext(ign -> value.incrementAndGet())
              .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
              .doOnNext(ign -> value.incrementAndGet())
              .doOnNext(ign -> value.incrementAndGet())
              .filter(String::isEmpty))
      .verifyComplete();
  assertThat(value.get()).isEqualTo(3);
}
```

What is the difference here between doOnEach and doOnNext?